# Drawing a vector in tikz with a coordinate value of sqrt(3)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, amsmath, tikz-styles

I am trying to plot a vector with the coordinates (sqrt(3), 1). Latex won't accept the square root or 3^(1/2). Do I need to manually write in the decimal number every time I have a square root coordinate?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my style, xtick={-1,0,...,1}, ytick={-3,-2,...,3},
xmin=-2, xmax=2, ymin=-3, ymax=3
]
\draw[->, thick, blue](0,0) -- (-\sqrt(3),1)node[right] {$\vec z_1$};
\draw[->, thick, blue](0,0) -- (\sqrt(3),0)node[above,sloped] {$\vec z_2$};
\draw[->, thick, blue](0,0) -- (0,1)node[above,sloped] {$\vec z_1+ \vec z_2$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome! You need braces and *no* backslash, e.g. `({-sqrt(3)},1)` and `({sqrt(3)},0)`. The braces are necessary because otherwise the parser gets confused, and `\sqrt` is a macro that *typesets* a square root whereas `sqrt` is a pgf function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you don't need to write in the decimal number. This will work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->, thick, blue](0,0) -- ({-sqrt(3)},1)node[right] {$\vec z_1$};
\draw[->, thick, blue](0,0) -- ({sqrt(3)},0)node[above,sloped] {$\vec z_2$};
\draw[->, thick, blue](0,0) -- (0,1)node[above,sloped] {$\vec z_1+ \vec z_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```